# Can I mark a Google Groups topic as unread?

Tags: google-groups

How can I mark a Google Groups topic that I click accidentally as unread to know that I still not read it at all?

Comment: I assume you mean from the web interface. No, you can't. Oddly enough, you can only mark messages as "read" but not the opposite.

Comment: @Krampus Thanks for your comment. Yes, I was talking from the web interface. If you reply this question I could accept it as the reply and "close" the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I assume you mean from the web interface.)

Unfortunately, no, you can't. (At least at present.)

Oddly enough, you can only mark messages as "read" but not the opposite.

Comment: Still seems to be true as of Aug 2021, both in the desktop and the mobile versions of the website.